# Looking for the code in twentyten that allows users to select images for the header/banner

Tags: theme-development, theme-twenty-ten

I am looking for the code that renders the below page. Where can I find it, it does not appear to be in functions.php?

[image]

I want to learn how they allow users to upload images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you are looking for is in functions.php (line 106 to 211).

To understand what they have done in TwentyTen, I would suggest that you read the following:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_custom_image_header

Comment: Technically speaking, the only code that the *developer* has to add to `functions.php` is a call to `add_custom_image_header()` (ideally, with related callback functions). WordPress itself does all of the heavy lifting. See also: [Appearance: Header Screen](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Header_SubPanel)